# Cloned Windows 7 to new HDD and want to change the drive letter to C

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, mbr

I used Clonezilla to clone my existing hard drive to a new one I bought. I then changed the BIOS to set the new drive as the first in the boot sequence. I'm pretty sure that I'm still running Windows 7 on the old drive.  My old drive is marked as C.

Now that I don't have a disk drive any more, how I do I swap the drive letter from `J:` to `C:`?

I tried to change it in the disk management section of "Manage", but it reports: "the parameter is incorrect".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran the windows 7 recovery disk. I ran the startup repair. I went to the commnand prompt and ran all of the [bootrec command options](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392?wa=wsignin1.0).

I think this made some progress but didn't fix it.

Last I used the command prompt as follows:

```
cd [cd/dvd drive]
bootsect /nt60 sys /mbr
```

And this fixed it!  The command was found [thanks to this youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9JFrmDubY5M&feature=g-hist).

Answer (score 0):

First try to remove your old hard drive from boot sequence and if that won't work unplug it.

Comment: Can you add more context to this answer to explain **why** it solves the problem. At the moment it's little more than a comment.

Comment: @Bougatsas this doesn't address how to rename the drive letter to C

Comment: @Bougatsas I unplugged the old hard drive, and the Windows Boot Manager now reports: "Windows failed to start...".